# CakePhp 2.x getClientIp returns ::1

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

Currently I am now using the RequestHandlerComponent.

```
public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Flash',
        'RequestHandler',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'messages',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

In getting the ip address, I am using this as what was stated in the documentation.

```
$this->request->clientIp()
```

And also I enabled the proxy by adding this:

```
$this->request->trustProxy = true;
```

So it will look like this:

```
$this->request->trustProxy = true;
$clientIp = $this->request->clientIp();
```

Instead of getting 192.168.XXX.XX8 (an IPv4 ip address example), I get ::1. What I'am trying to achieve is get my IPv4 Address.

Can someone help me badly into this? I will really much appreciate it. Thankyousomuch!

Comment: `::1` is an IPv6 address. Presumably, that's what your client is using?

Comment: Yes you are right. A bit configuration in httpd.conf solves the issue coz currently I am working localhost